# Количество записей в файле

Tags: файлы, c++

Пытаюсь посчитать количество записей в файле по формуле (размер_файла)/(размер_одной_записи), но дело в том, что в записи содержится строка, кол-во символов которой в каждой записи может быть разное, соответственно эта формуле не работает, так как размер файла будет зависеть от длин строк записей.

Так же в файл к каждой записи еще добавляются некоторые поля, но это не совсем важно, ибо их размер фиксирован.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class ONE
{
    char name[10];
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    ONE(char* name, int a, int b)
    {
        strcpy(this->name, name);
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const ONE& o)
    {
        return out << "Имя: " << o.name << endl << "a = " << o.a << endl << "b = " << o.b  << endl;

    }
};

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    ONE obj1("Vasya", 1, 2);
    ONE obj2("Fedya", 3, 4);
    ONE obj3("Fedya123", 3, 4);

    ofstream fout("file.txt", ios_base::app);

    fout << obj1 << obj2 << obj3;

    fout.seekp(0, ios::end);

    int fsize = fout.tellp();

    system("pause");

}
```

Как посчитать кол-во записей в файле?

Comment: Немного не понял, что является записью. Строка? Или количество слов?

Comment: Запись -- это совокупность трех полей класса ONE.

Comment: заголовок у файла нужно делать, чтобы не читать все блоки, заголовок - фиксированное(не обязательно, но так легче) количество байт в начале или конце файла.

Comment: а что будет, если в конце или начале файла вставить поле из четырех байтов под поле целого типа для записи в него количества записей? Тогда можно его за раз считывать, и мы будем знать, сколько записей в файле.

Answer (score 1):

[@Wersel](/users/30504/wersel), поскольку каждая запись (а по сути строка) завершается символом `'\n'`, то достаточно просто подсчитать их количество, например:

```
int n = 0;
char c;
while (inpf.get(c))
  if (c == '\n')
    n++;
```

Comment: Одна запись три '\n;

Comment: @JK_Action, не понял что Вы имели в виду.

Comment: на одну запись приходится три символа '\n'. Идея вашего алгоритма правильная, только нужно счетчик разделить на три.

Comment: @JK_Action, с чего бы это? У ТС речь о том, что одна запись это одна строка. Как широко известно (общепринято) строки в файле заканчиваются символом новой строки. Вот и получаем -- один `\n` на запись.

Answer (score 0):

раз каждая запись разного размера, значит придется с самого начала прочитать все записи до конца. И этим собственно их и посчитать. Да, при этом можно читать "бегло". То есть, к примеру, под строки место не выделять, а просто смещать указатель.

Answer (score 0):

[[@Wersel](/users/30504/wersel)](/users/30504/wersel), во-первых, если используете ввод-вывод в стиле С++, используйте также класс string, с ним намного проще, чем с указателями на char. Во-вторых, насколько я понял, в файле записи идут в порядке |строка||число||число| ? Так в чем проблема? Открывайте поток чтения из файла, объявляйте переменную счетчик, и в цикле while(fin >> name >> num1 >> num2) счетчик инкрементируйте. Число будет подсчитывать кол-во записей.

Или вам именно методом sizeof()/sizeof() нужно высчитать?